# Причастный оборот в технологии

Tags: синтаксис

Имеем следующий причастный оборот:
"трубопровод греющего пара, соединяющий вышеуказанное оборудование"
К какому слову в предложении относится причастный оборот - к "трубопровод" или "пара"?

Comment: к обоим, точнее это название элемента конструкции "трубопровод греющего пара".

Comment: Если бы пар мог соединять оборудование, то было бы так: пара (какого?), соединяющ**его**.

Answer (score 0):

к "трубопровод": пар не может соединять оборудование.